# Kafka python SSL hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for error

Tags: python, docker, ssl, apache-kafka, ssl-certificate

I am trying to configure locally kafka with SSL. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.9
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '32181:32181'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    healthcheck:
      test: "zookeeper-shell 127.0.01:32181 ls /"
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.9
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '29092:29092'
    depends_on:
      zookeeper:
        condition: service_healthy
    env_file: docker-compose-kafka.env
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka-1:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    healthcheck:
      test: kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka-1:29092 --list
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 4
    volumes:
      - ./ssl2:/ssl2

  py-app:
    image: python:3.9.16-bullseye
    volumes:
      - ./app-py:/app
      - ./ssl2:/ssl2
    depends_on:
      - kafka-1

volumes:
  bundle:
```

Here is `docker-compose-kafka.env`:

```bash
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS=6000
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SSL
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=EXTERNAL
KAFKA_SSL_PROTOCOL=TLS
KAFKA_SSL_CA_LOCATION=/ssl2/ca-cert
KAFKA_SSL_ENABLED_PROTOCOLS=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1

KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_TYPE=JKS
KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION=/ssl2/py2/kafka.server.keystore.jks
KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=123456
KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=123456

KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE=JKS
KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=/ssl2/py2/kafka.server.truststore.jks
KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=123456

KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH=required
KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM=

KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE=true
KAFKA_NUM_NETWORK_THREADS=1
KAFKA_NUM_IO_THREADS=1
KAFKA_BACKGROUND_THREADS=1
KAFKA_LOG_CLEANER_THREADS=1

KAFKA_LOG_DIRS=/tmp/kafka_log
KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS=1
KAFKA_NUM_RECOVERY_THREADS_PER_DATA_DIR=1
KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS=1
```

And I am trying to produce a message via SSL like so:

```py
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='kafka-1:9092',
                          security_protocol='SSL',
                          ssl_check_hostname=True,
                          ssl_cafile='/ssl2/py2/CARoot.pem',
                          ssl_certfile='/ssl2/py2/ca-cert',
                          ssl_keyfile='/ssl2/py2/ca-key',
                          ssl_password='123456')

producer.send("example", bytes('Hello Kafka!123','utf-8'))
producer.flush()
```

And I am getting this error:

```bash
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'kafka-1'. (_ssl.c:1129)
```

And the error on kafka logs:

```bash
kafka-1_1    | [2023-04-25 07:32:04,434] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1] Failed authentication with /172.28.0.4 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

Here is scripts that I am using to generate SSL and keystore:

```bash
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias kafka-1 -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -genkey
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout ca-key -out ca-cert -days 365
keytool -keystore kafka.client.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -importcert -file ca-cert
keytool -keystore kafka.server.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -importcert -file ca-cert
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias kafka-1 -certreq -file cert-file
openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in cert-file -out cert-signed -days 365 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:123456
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -importcert -file ca-cert
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias kafka-1 -importcert -file cert-signed
keytool -exportcert -alias CARoot -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -rfc -file CARoot.pem -storepass 123456
```

When it is being asked `Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []` while generating ca-cert/ca-key I am adding "kafka-1".

Could someone please help to understand what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!